# PiCamera() error. How do I fix this problem?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

If I run `vcgencmd get_camera` it gives me `supported=1 detected=1`

If I run `raspistill -o test.jpg` the test.jpg file appear but gives this message

```
mmal: mmal_vc_shm_init: could not initialize vc shared memory service
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to initialise shm for 'vc.camera_info' (7:EIO)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.camera_info' (7)
mmal: Failed to create camera_info component
```

Then, I try to run this python code below, but it gives me this error message

```
from picamera import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera()
```

Error:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_shm_init: could not initialize vc shared memory service
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to initialise shm for 'vc.camera_info' (7:EIO)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.camera_info' (7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 367, in __init__
    with mo.MMALCameraInfo() as camera_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2346, in __init__
    super(MMALCameraInfo, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 633, in __init__
    prefix="Failed to create MMAL component %s" % self.component_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': I/O error
```

Inside the `/boot/config.txt`  I already have

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that rewrite the boot directory.

1. Install new Raspberry OS onto an empty disk or sd card.
2. Copy all of the files and folders, except of config.txt and commandline.txt, from the new `/boot` directory to the old `/boot` directory.
3. Restart your PI.

Comment: I just installed a brand new image using the official Raspberry Pi OS Image installer. Same issue as OP and following the documentation [picamera.readthedocs.io](picamera.readthedocs.io). I'm looking into solving the issue but your solution is currently not a solution.

Comment: Agree with @rbaleksandar - I'm on a fresh install of RaspiOs  for Pi Zero (32bit armhf, the 1.1gb lastest img, not lite/full), and following docs and this isn't working...

However, previously I had script from [picamera receipes2](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html) working - same release date, but I used lite img and then installed mate desktop....    I'm going to reinstall based on that, will reply if learn anything worth sharing